# How do i limit the user for only specific words input

Tags: java, io, textfield

In my program in the input textField, i want the user to be able to input only few specific words from a list , What would be the best way to go at this?

-thanks

Comment: Is this an HTML input or a Swing text field? A validation method will work on both cases but you can use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html if it's Swing.

Comment: Why not use a `JComboBox`?

Comment: if u want only few specific words use filter.

Comment: you should pharse the question in more detail !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is exactly your purpose? 
Maybe you are taking the wrong approach.

If you want to allow only some words, maybe you need a combo box with some pre-built phrases.
If you want a system like the stack overflow tag system (only defined tags) maybe you want to use something like a shuttle list.

Comment: What is a shuttle list? Do you know of any good links for reading on?

Comment: It really depends on what kind of application you are building, for example if you are using richfaces for a web app you could look at the <rich:listShuttle> component here: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_listShuttle.html

Comment: Anyway, basically it consist of two list of objects, one the available and the other the used. You can move objects (in your case words) from one list to another, add all, remove all...